# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql

i have this `MySQL` table for news categories:

`id - name - parent`

1:
now I  need to list parent/child categories into `<optgroup><optgroup>`.

PHP CODE:

```
$options    = array();
$categories = mysql_query("
  SELECT 
    id, name, p.name AS parent 
  FROM 
    " . CATS . " AS child
  INNER JOIN
    " . CATS . " AS p ON p.id = child.parent
");
foreach($categories as $category) { // LINE 734
  $parent = $category['parent'];
  if (! isset($options[$parent])) $options[$parent] = array();
  $options[$parent][$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}
echo "<select>";
foreach($options as $group => $option) {
  printf('<optgroup label="%s">', $group);
  foreach ($option as $id => $label) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $id, $label);
  }
  printf('</optgroup>');
}
echo "</select>";
```

PROBLEM:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\news.php on line 734`

UPDATE: I test with `$categories` `array` and see my code worked. if $categories MySQL result Like this:

```
$categories = array(
  array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Label 1', 'parent' => 'Parent 1'),
  array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Label 2', 'parent' => 'Parent 2'),
  array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Label 3', 'parent' => 'Parent 1'),
  array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Label 4', 'parent' => 'Parent 1'),
  array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Label 5', 'parent' => 'Parent 1'),
  array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Label 6', 'parent' => 'Parent 3'),
  array('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Label 7', 'parent' => 'Parent 8'),
  array('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Label 8', 'parent' => 'Parent 4'),
);
```

How To Fix My Problem!?

2: in update news page,I need To select News cats in this menu. My mean is: if `$newscatid = $catid` selected Option.(`option value = $newscatid`) How To update my code for this?

Comment: Did you read documentation about (mysql_query)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php]?

Comment: Add this line above line number 734 $categories=mysql_fetch_array($categories);

Comment: @AltafHussain: This Won't Work: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 735`

Comment: @emix This question is from 2013.

Comment: I’ve cast a vote so the question can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call a query and use it like that. Your query returns a result set and you need to iterate through that. Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT 
    id, name, p.name AS parent 
  FROM 
    " . CATS . " AS child
  INNER JOIN
    " . CATS . " AS p ON p.id = child.parent
");
while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $parent = $category['parent'];
  if (! isset($options[$parent])) $options[$parent] = array();
  $options[$parent][$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}
```

Also, you really need to switch to `mysqli`
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: This Won't Work: `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 735`

Comment: Did you change line 726 to `$query`? I changed it for clarity

Comment: No, I replace with `$categories`!!

Comment: Ok, then it's likely your query failed then. Can you output [mysql_error](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)?

Answer (score -1):

mysql_query function returns Resource not Array ,
check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

try this

```
while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)){ // LINE 734
  $parent = $category['parent'];
  if (! isset($options[$parent])) $options[$parent] = array();
  $options[$parent][$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}
```

by the way , you are using deprecated mysql functions ...

Comment: This won't work. You have to have this inside a `while` loop. `foreach` expects an array.